# zfs change block size without going offline

Tags: mirror, zpool

Given a raidz1 vdev on FreeBSD 10 with this config:

```
root@gw:~ # zpool status
  pool: data
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices are configured to use a non-native block size.
        Expect reduced performance.
action: Replace affected devices with devices that support the
        configured block size, or migrate data to a properly configured
        pool.
  scan: resilvered 26.1G in 0h43m with 0 errors on Sat Dec 21 07:07:41 2013
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        data        ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada1    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native
            ada2    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ada3    ONLINE       0     0     0  block size: 512B configured, 4096B native

errors: No known data errors
```

I would like to correct for the blocksize. Is it possible to change the blocksize without offlining the pool? I just wanted to know if these are the right commands to execute. I could try without asking, but the devil never sleeps...

```
zpool detach data ada1
zpool labelclear ada1
zpool attach data ada1
```

Is it the right way to do it?

UPDATE - things I have tried:

- "zpool remove" could be used to remove ada1 before clearing and adding it again. But "zpool remove" does not support raidz vdevs.
- "zpool replace --f ada1" could be used to forcedly rebuild ada1 like if it was a new devide, but zpool does not allow this (even not forcedly) for a device that is already part of an active

I believe that I could achieve this the following way:

- shut down the system
- remove ada1 and wipe data on it completely
- put back ada1
- start up the system
- then issue "zpool replace data ada1"

Could this work? But only after shutting down the computer completely. :-(

Comment: Ugh, I just realized that it is not a mirror. It iz a raidz1 array... what a pity. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I think the command you're looking for is `zpool offline`, like this:

```
zpool offline data ada1
zpool labelclear ada1
zpool replace data ada1 ada1
```

That last `replace` might not work specifying the first `ada1`. If it doesn't, use `zpool list` or `zdb` to get the disk GUID. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/305830/replacing-a-dead-disk-in-a-zpool

Comment: I got this: labelclear operation failed.
        Vdev /dev/ada1 is a member (ACTIVE), of pool "data".
        To remove label information from this device, export or destroy
        the pool, or remove /dev/ada1 from the configuration of this pool
        and retry the labelclear operation